# Try not to have a null or undefined value in a JSON to use Object.keys function

Tags: json, typescript, typeof

I have a JSON which looks like :

```
{
'total_count': 6,
'incomplete_results': false,
'items': [
  {
    'url': 'https://api.github.com/repos/Samhot/GenIHM/issues/2',
    'repository_url': 'https://api.github.com/repos/Samhot/GenIHM',
    'comments_url': 'https://api.github.com/repos/Samhot/GenIHM/issues/2/comments',
    'events_url': 'https://api.github.com/repos/Samhot/GenIHM/issues/2/events',
    'html_url': 'https://github.com/Samhot/GenIHM/issues/2',
    'id': 293234257,
    'number': 2,
    'title': 'Créer serveur pour API RESTful',
    'user': {
      'login': 'Samhot',
      'id': 7148311,
      'avatar_url': 'https://avatars3.githubusercontent.com/u/7148311?v=4',
      'gravatar_id': '',
      'url': 'https://api.github.com/users/Samhot',
      'html_url': 'https://github.com/Samhot',
      'followers_url': 'https://api.github.com/users/Samhot/followers',
      'subscriptions_url': 'https://api.github.com/users/Samhot/subscriptions',
      'organizations_url': 'https://api.github.com/users/Samhot/orgs',
      'repos_url': 'https://api.github.com/users/Samhot/repos',
      'received_events_url': 'https://api.github.com/users/Samhot/received_events',
      'type': 'User',
      'site_admin': false
    },
    'state': 'open',
    'locked': false,
    'assignee': null,
  }
 ]
};
```

I try to get all the keys from this JSON with the `getDeepKeys()` function :

```
getDeepKeys2(obj) {
  const keys = Object.keys(obj);
  const childKeys = keys
    .map(key => obj[key])
    .map(
      value =>
        Array.isArray(value)
          ? this.getDeepKeys2(value[0]) : typeof value === 'object'
            ? this.getDeepKeys2(value) : []
    )
    .reduce((acc, keys) => [...acc, ...keys], []);
  this.dispotest = [...keys, ...childKeys];
  return this.dispotest;
}
```

**This function works perfectly as long as the JSON doesn't contain a *null* or *undefined* value like `'assignee': null`.**

If this type of value is present in my JSON the function returns :

> ERROR TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object

I think to use the **`typeof`** function to do `if (typeof value === null { return null; }` but i don't know where i have to apply this...

Thanks for help !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My gut feeling is your attempt:

```
if (typeof value === null { return null; }
```

Simply needs to be:

```
if (value == null) { return null; }
```

Note: the double `==` is deliberate as this will handle both `null` and `undefined`.

Full Example:

```
function getDeepKeys2(obj) {
  const keys = Object.keys(obj);
  const childKeys = keys
    .map(key => obj[key])
    .map(value => {
      if (value == null || (value.length != null && value.length === 0)) {
        return null;
      }
      return Array.isArray(value)
        ? this.getDeepKeys2(value[0]) : typeof value === 'object'
        ? this.getDeepKeys2(value) : []
    })
    .reduce((acc, keys) => [...acc, ...keys], []);
  this.dispotest = [...keys, ...childKeys];
  return this.dispotest;
}
```

Output (in console):

```
(29) […]
0: "total_count"
1: "incomplete_results"
2: "items"
3: "url"
4: "repository_url"
5: "comments_url"
6: "events_url"
7: "html_url"
8: "id"
9: "number"
10: "title"
11: "user"
12: "state"
13: "locked"
14: "assignee"
15: "login"
16: "id"
17: "avatar_url"
18: "gravatar_id"
19: "url"
20: "html_url"
21: "followers_url"
22: "subscriptions_url"
23: "organizations_url"
24: "repos_url"
25: "received_events_url"
26: "type"
27: "site_admin"
28: null
length: 29
__proto__: Array []
```

Comment: Please @Fenton can you look at my last question ? Thanks

Comment: @samhot updated to handle empty arrays... also, I'll need to remove your answer as it is a question, rather than an answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it works ! And i removed my answer sorry